# Handling incomplete type errors in C

Tags: c

I have a struct called 'residence' below. It contains a `person_list` struct where the `person_list` struct contains a struct for each person.

```
typedef struct a_person
{
char name [MAX_LENGTH];
int age;

} person;

typedef struct person_list
{
struct person people[MAX_ALLOWED];

} personList;

struct residence  {
    char residence_name [MAX_LENGTH];
    struct personList resident_list;
};
```

I'm getting these errors upon compilation:

```
error: resident_list; has incomplete type

error: array type has incomplete element type (@struct person
people[MAX_ALLOWED];)
```

---

If you need additional code or information please don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Do you mean `struct person` or `struct a_person` ?

Comment: `personList;` is a typedef name for `struct person_list` . You are confusing yourself when you say `struct personList  resident_list;`

Comment: @wildplasser Should it be struct personList resident_list?

Comment: @librik typedef struct a_person is how I defined it

Comment: @BDillan: my personal advice for beginners is: avoid using typedefs, until you really need them. (this may sound cocky, but C is hard enough without typedefs, and you seldomly need them)

Comment: @BDillan, you can reference the type of array `people` elements as `struct a_person` (because of the actual type definition) or as `person` (because of the new type typedef declaration), but you have not declared the type `struct person` anywhere in your code, so a pointer to it is an incomplete type (that what's the compiler complainting about) It can be used, but with limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could predeclare every `struct` that you are further defining, e.g. by starting your file (or your header file) with

```
  struct a_person;  // should be person_st
  struct person_list; // should be person_list_st
```

then you may have a pointer to such `struct` (even without having defined the fields of that `struct` yet).

However, when you define a `struct` by listing all its fields, every field should have a size known to the compiler.

Some further hints (including conventions):

- you could (and I do, conventionally) name every `struct` tag ending with e.g. `_st` (this is a *convention* that *I do like to follow*)
- you can make a `typedef` together with the `struct` declaration, e.g.

  ```
   typedef struct a_person_st Person;
  ```

  BTW, I am following the convention (inspired by [GTK](http://gtk.org/)) that a structure type starts with a capital letter.
- I don't recommend having `typedef` for pointers. Being a pointer type is really important in C, and I feel it should be kept apparent. So I recommend against <strike>`typedef Person*PersonPtr;`</strike> (but again, this is *my convention*).
- You would later define the `struct` by listing its fields, e.g.

  ```
  struct person_st { // or Person 
   char name[MAX_LENGTH];
   int age;
  }; // end of definition of struct person_st
  ```

---

You might be interested (assuming a C99 or C11 compiler) by [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) (it is a C feature, not a C++ one, and that flexible array member should *always* be the last of its containing `struct`).

Comment: There is no reason to have the `struct` tag different from the `typedef` name, really. Why using two identifiers when you just can have one?

Comment: Because I feel it is more readable. I know they belong to different namespaces. As I said, it is a convention.